# MySQL : Backup Database with selected table

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL database.I wanted to take database backup, only for selected table.
I used 'mysqldump' command for taking dump of entire db.But, what should be done for taking dump of only selected tables.

Comment: mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql

Comment: I am having more than one table.So can i use something like "mysqldump db_name table_name1,table_name2,... > table_name.sql"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following command you can take a dump of selected tables

```
mysqldump -u user -p database table1 table2 tableN > filename.sql
```

`table1 table2 tableN` are the table names you want to take backup